# When exporting Word review comments, how do you reference the sentence related to a comment?

Tags: macros, vbscript, ms-word

I am trying to export a Word document's review comments.  I want to export the sentence selection that was commented on followed by the comment.

Screen shot of the image: http://jspeaks.com/mswordcomment.png

I have found code to loop through the document comments, but I cannot figure out how to reference the sentence selection that the comment was related to.

The current logic is:

```
Sub ExportComments()
    Dim s As String
    Dim cmt As Word.Comment
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    For Each cmt In ActiveDocument.Comments
        s = s & cmt.Initial & cmt.Index & "," & cmt.Range.Text & vbCr
    Next

    Set doc = Documents.Add
    doc.Range.Text = s
End Sub
```

I tinkered with Selection.Range, however I cannot determine the proper object or property that contains the referenced sentence.

I would like to produce output like the following (if we use the example in picture above):

Sentence: Here are more sentences that contain interesting facts - Comment: This is an interesting fact.
Sentence: Here are more sentences that contain interesting facts.  Here are more sentences that contain interesting facts. - Comment: This is a very interesting fact

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found someone on another site to solve this question.

The key to the solution is: cmt.Scope.FormattedText

Here is the function revised:

```
Sub ExportComments()
    Dim s As String
    Dim cmt As Word.Comment
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    For Each cmt In ActiveDocument.Comments
        s = s & "Text: " & cmt.Scope.FormattedText & " -> "
        s = s & "Comments: " & cmt.Initial & cmt.Index & ":" & cmt.Range.Text & vbCr
    Next

    Set doc = Documents.Add
    doc.Range.Text = s
End Sub
```

Comment: Great that you have a solution. You can go ahead and accept your own answer as the correct one (the checkmark).

Answer (score 3):

I have gathered several pieces of code and came to this solution:

```
Sub CopyCommentsToExcel()
'Create in Word vba
'TODO: set a reference to the Excel object library (Tools --> Reference --> Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object library)

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim HeadingRow As Integer
HeadingRow = 3

Dim cmtRef As Range

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add ' create a new workbook
With xlWB.Worksheets(1)
' Create report info
    .Cells(1, 1).Formula = "Reviewed document:"

' Create Heading
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 1).Formula = "Index"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 2).Formula = "Page"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 3).Formula = "Line"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 4).Formula = "Comment"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 5).Formula = "Reviewer"
    .Cells(HeadingRow, 6).Formula = "Date"
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
        .Cells(2, 1).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Parent
        .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 1).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Index
        .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 2).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Reference.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 3).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Reference.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
        .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 4).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Range
        .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 5).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Initial
        .Cells(i + HeadingRow, 6).Formula = Format(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
        '        .Cells(i + 1, 3).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Parent
        '        .Cells(i + 1, 3).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Application
        '        .Cells(i + 1, 7).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Author
    Next i
End With
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Most valuable help from [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/export-word-review-comments-in-excel/54818c46-b7d2-416c-a4e3-3131ab68809c)

Comment: user662182:
Thanks for the excellent contribution, but this macro will not compile under Word 2007 until the user
follows the instructions in the TODO comment of the VBA source.
It is important to note that if the user executes without doing this, the Tools->References option is grayed out... RESET the current macro in the VB Editor, THEN the option is active!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the highlighted reference text that a comment relates to, add these lines of code with others like them:

.Cells(HeadingRow, 7).Formula = "Reference text"
.Cells(i + HeadingRow, 7).Formula = ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Scope

Also, I had to comment out the following lines of code, perhaps because Excel was open (not sure)
'Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
'Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

Otherwise, the program above worked like a charm. Thanks!